# Kaspersky Anti-Banner System is blocking AdSense in my website

Tags: adsense, adblock, kaspersky

Recently I noticed that Kaspersky Anti-Banner system is blocking all adds inside my website. For this reason I am loosing my ad-revenue.

Is there any fix for this issue?
I am already checking Ad-blockers successfully, but that code is not working with Kaspersky Anti-Banner.

Answer (score 1):

That's the whole idea behind the good anti-banner systems — to block the banners.

You can enable detailed logger inside the Kaspersky product (e.g. KIS/KTS/KCS) and see which requests are blocked, perhaps, it can help you.

P.S. The built-in Kaspersky Anti-Banner is not the cutting edge solution on the market, uBlock Origin is far more advanced and is capable not only blocking the AD loading, but also manipulating the DOM to hide the already loaded un-wnated content.